# kitkat 4.4.4 connecting usb devices to samsung tab e

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I need to connect a USB printer and a Vivitar camera to a Galaxy Tab e. I currently have a USB OTG cable, and a USB-A --> Mini-B cable

Answer (score 0):

**For the printer**, you'll need a USB-A --> B cable, along with:
[Print Hand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printhand.premium&hl=en), [Printer Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.premium&hl=en), or a similar app from the Play Store.

Make sure your printer is compatible with the app you choose before dropping the $.